# How to split time range into intervals in a 'Select' SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm a newbie in SQL and I'm writing a few SQL queries offlate at work.
I've come across a certain blocker, can you guys help me with a solution or an alternative?

Here's the query that I use (using just 1 row as reference):

```
Select 
USER_NAME, 
TIME(CONVERT_TZ(START_TIME, '+00:00','America/Los_Angeles')) as 'PST Start',
TIME(CONVERT_TZ(END_TIME, '+00:00','America/Los_Angeles')) as 'PST End',
name as 'Type',
date(start_time) as 'Date',
WORKGROUP_NAME
from USER_SCHEDULE_INSTANCES 
where user_name = 'prateeth' 
and date(START_TIME) = '2018-01-01'
limit 1
```

and this is the output

```
USER_NAME   PST Start   PST End     Date        Type    WORKGROUP_NAME
prateeth    06:00:00    09:00:00    2018-01-01  Work    NACS Command Center
```

what do I do to split this into half hour intervals, without using a macro and to receive the output like this:

```
USER_NAME   PST Start   PST End     Date        Type    WORKGROUP_NAME
prateeth    06:00:00    06:30:00    2018-01-01  Work    NACS Command Center
prateeth    06:30:00    07:00:00    2018-01-01  Work    NACS Command Center
prateeth    07:00:00    07:30:00    2018-01-01  Work    NACS Command Center
prateeth    07:30:00    08:00:00    2018-01-01  Work    NACS Command Center
prateeth    08:00:00    08:30:00    2018-01-01  Work    NACS Command Center
prateeth    08:30:00    09:00:00    2018-01-01  Work    NACS Command Center
```

Comment: There might be a more elegant method, but I like creating a reference table here that you join to (cross join is acceptable) that has the time frames recorded in it.

Comment: I like the same approach because the performance is pretty good.

Comment: @Prateeth . . . This is a rather complicated query to be getting started with.

Comment: Well then, Amateur, not a starter :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment to answer.  Create a time table and populate with the time frames you are looking for.  something along these lines:

```
Table Name: Dim_Time 
example data:

ID    starttime   endtime
1     06:00       06:30
2     06:30       07:00
etc
```

When you need to split to time frames, in your from statement cross join to this table.

```
From  USER_SCHEDULE_INSTANCES 
join dim_time on 1=1
```

You can add a second ID column in this time table that will allow you to have multiple 'versions' of this time break down as well.

Hope that is clear, comment if you need more.

Comment: I like this idea, but I do not have access to create a table on this database (access is very restricted).
Any way to put this in the query?
Also, can you please elaborate the ON statement, I'm not able to figure out how to put it.
Thank you so much for the reply

Comment: I've kinda got it, I've created a dummy table within the query using the DUAL table.